# How to get a single output by 2 different way of the process using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on selenium and TestNG with java. I have some problem about how to handle the popup. In here, I have 2 process at a time. if I click on the button and it has an ingredient, then it will open a popup, otherwise it will add in a cart directly. So i used:

```
@Test         
 public void ingredient_Popup()      
 {   
     String ingre_Title="Choose product choices...";   
      String ingre_Title1=d.findElement(By.className("modal-dialog")).getText();
     if(ingre_Title.contentEquals(ingre_Title1))         
      {      
        d.findElement(By.id("ingredient_quantity")).sendKeys("1");
         d.findElement(By.linkText("SUBMIT")).click();       
     }        
    else     
     {       
d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/span[2]/button")).click();          
}      
And also i used  (II)    
 @Test        
 public void ingredient_Popup()WebElement element;       
 try     
 {      
  element = d.findElement(By.className("modal-dialog"));   >}            
catch(NoSuchElementException n)           
{   
  element = null;   
    }       
{      
    if(element !=null)          
{            
        d.findElement(By.id("ingredient_quantity")).sendKeys("1");            
d.findElement(By.linkText("SUBMIT")).click();       
   }           
else         
{    
        d.findElement(By.className("btn btn-default btn-number")).click();         
    }        
 }      
 And i used, isenabled, Contains, equals, isdisplayed, isElementPresent         
if(ingre_Title.isEnabled())        
    {      
    d.findElement(By.id("ingredient_quantity")).sendKeys("1");          
d.findElement(By.linkText("SUBMIT")).click();       
    }      
    else       
    {     
       d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/span[2]/button")).click();      
 }         
 And i tried a lot, Nothing is working. i'm getting NoSuchElementException    
error.
```

So Kindly anyone make a code and share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is to identify the scenario correctly. Just find the existence of the expected element in case of that particular scenario else otherwise.

For example, consider after clicking a button you might have two scenario's. Scenario A has element A and scenario B has element B then,

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("button")).click;

//Identifying the scenario by checking the presence of the element
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("A")).size>0)
{
  //IF THIS IS TRUE NOW YOU ARE IN SCENARIO A
  //DO YOUR STUFF ACCORDING TO SCENARIO A
}
else if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("B")).size>0)
{
  //IF THIS IS TRUE NOW YOU ARE IN SCENARIO B
  //DO YOUR STUFF INCASE OF SCENARIO B
}
```

Modify the logic as per your logic but the trick is in findelements. You can use this to check the presence of an element easily.

Hope this helps.
Thanks.